# angular Material Datatable action icon didn't display

Tags: angular, datatable

I'm working angular project and I'm new, I have created my own Datatable using angular material and everything fine but after adding an algorithm for making my table resizable I found that the action buttons (one for updating and for deleting) didn't work anymore! PLz guys help

comp.html

```
<div
      mwlResizable
      [enableGhostResize]="true"
      [resizeEdges]="{ bottom: true, right: true, top: true, left: true }"
      (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)"
      style="border:1px dashed black;" [ngStyle]="style"
      class="res_box" >
    <div class="box">
        <div class="mat" >
         <div class="tableone">
            <div class="search-div">
                <button mat-raised-button (click)="add_new_user()">
                  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <span>Ajouter</span>
                </button>
                <mat-form-field class="search-form-field">
                    <input type="text" matInput [(ngModel)]="searchkey" placeholder="Filtrer" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="applyfilter()">
                    <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"*ngIf="searchkey" (click)="onfilterClear()">
                      <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                    </button>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
             <mat-table [dataSource]="listdata" matSort>
               <ng-container matColumnDef = "Index">
                 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Index</mat-header-cell>
                 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.index}}</mat-cell>
               </ng-container>
               <ng-container matColumnDef = "Name">
                 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Full name</mat-header-cell>
                 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</mat-cell>
               </ng-container>
               <ng-container matColumnDef = "Gender">
                 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Gender</mat-header-cell>
                 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.gender}}</mat-cell>
               </ng-container>
               <ng-container matColumnDef = "Age">
                 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Age</mat-header-cell>
                 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.age}}</mat-cell>
               </ng-container>
               <ng-container matColumnDef = "EyeColor">
                 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>EyeColor</mat-header-cell>
                 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.eyeColor}}</mat-cell>
               </ng-container>
               <ng-container matColumnDef = "actions">
                 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
                 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let rows">
                   <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>launch</mat-icon></button>
                   <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></button>
                 </mat-cell>
               </ng-container>
               <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
               <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
             </mat-table>
             <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" [pageSize]="5"></mat-paginator>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

comp.ts

```
 fake_arr: fake[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Index','Name','Gender','Age','EyeColor'];
  listdata: MatTableDataSource<any>;  

  @ViewChild(MatSort,null) sort: MatSort;//{ static: true }
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator,null) paginator: MatPaginator;
  searchkey: string;

  constructor(private service: FakeService) {; }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getFakeiems().subscribe((arr: fake[])=>{
      arr.forEach(element => {
         console.log(element); 
      });
      this.listdata = new MatTableDataSource(arr);
      this.listdata.sort = this.sort;
      this.listdata.paginator = this.paginator;
  });
 }
 onfilterClear(){
  this.searchkey = "";
}
applyfilter(){
  this.listdata.filter = this.searchkey.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

com.module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DepensesGeneralComponent, GestionDesChauffeursComponent],
  imports: [
      CommonModule,
      RouterModule.forChild(routes),
      MatButtonModule,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatRippleModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatPaginatorModule,
      FormsModule,
      ResizableModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatSortModule
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatRippleModule

    ]
})
```

[image: The result]

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Do the functions not work, or is something else the problem?

Comment: it doesn't display I will edit my qst and add a photo of the result

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it just I need to add action name into displayedColumns